# ASP.NET - How to use a user control from a different application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How do I utilize a user control from Application B within Application A?

Application A is a VB.NET App

Application B is a C# app.

This code attempts to register the control for usage in an aspx file:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Pager" Src="../ApplicationB/Controls/PagingControl.ascx" %>
```

I get the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: The virtual path '/ApplicationB/Controls/PagingControl.ascx' maps to another application, which is not allowed.
```

Can I use Application B's PagingControl.ascx within Application A?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net will only load binaries from either the GAC or from it's own folder structure. To use the control in both places you must compile it to an assembly that can be included in the bin folder for both applications.

Comment: I have a reference to Application B's DLL. Is there some way for me to utilize the PagingControl ASCX in Application A? I believe this is what you're referring to. Thanks